# What is a good place for teachers to share self-created content?

Tags: undergraduate-education, secondary-education, online-instruction, problem-solving, online

I am a high school mathematics teacher and I regularly create problems and their solutions for my students. It has always lingered in my mind that this content can also benefit others.

What would be a good place for me to share it?

Hosting own website would just be an island with no visitors. I believe that I ideally need a place with a regular stream of problem solving visitors, some of whom could then benefit from my content as well.

Comment: Here are some ideas: https://www.edutopia.org/blog/sharing-best-work-other-teachers-peter-paccone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the medium of the content?

If they are videos, then YouTube would probably be first option but if they are, say, pdfs, then you might have to make a blog and then upload to that there. It still might feel like an island at first but it will gain traffic from your students and then other people who find it in search results. There are also problem-solving forums which one could join, but the rules of posting content would need to be read beforehand.